# How do I get the current mouse position in C++ / OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, mouse, glut

I know that I can use a Mouse callback function for when a user clicks the mouse, but what if I want to know the current x/y position without the user clicking?

Will I have to use a different callback that gets called on any mouse movement and keep track of the x/y myself or is there a function I can call within GLUT/OpenGL to get it?

Comment: This is more related to glut than OpenGL.  Things like mouse position are usually handled by the OS, and have little to do with either OpenGL or C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Register a glutPassiveMotionFunc callback function

See info about [callbacks](http://titanium.mountunion.edu/cs/cs480/sp07/glutcallbackhints.html)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the glutMotionFunc/glutPassiveMotionFunc callback to track mouse movement independent of mouse clicks.

[7.6 glutMotionFunc, glutPassiveMotionFunc](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node51.html#SECTION00086000000000000000)